# replace guard let try with do and catch

Tags: swift

I have following implementation and where I am propogating issues to ViewController to display an alert properly. As you see in my code, I have use **guard let** and **try** all together in a single line. Which works but not recommended I guess.

What would be best to handle/refactor the code to handle each throw cases properly?

```
enum ServiceError: Error {
  case ClassroomApplicationCreation(Error)
  case ClassroomDoesNotExist(Error)
  case ClassRoomSelectionError
}

func createClassroom() throws -> String {
    guard let selectedClass = try findClassroom() else {
      throw ServiceError.ClassSelectionError
    }
    guard let classURL = URL(string: selectedClass) else {
      throw ServiceError.ClassroomDoesNotExist
    }
    let authority = try Authority(url: classURL)
    let configuration = ClassroomApplicationConfig(className: selectedClass, redirectUri: nil, authority: authority)
    do {
      return try ClassRoom(configuration: configuration)
    } catch {
      throw ServiceError.ClassroomApplicationCreation(error)
    }
}

func findClassroom() throws -> String? {
    guard
      let selectedClass = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedClass)
    else {
      throw ServiceError.ClassRoomSelectionError
    }
    do {
      return try serviceManager.retrieveClassroom(selectedClass)
    } catch {
      throw ServiceError.ClassRoomSelectionError
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is okay to forward along the Authority init, while the other errors have to be obfuscated?

Comment: IMO If your method throws you should not catch the errors there. Just throw the proper errors from your findClassroom method and the ClassRoom initializer.

Comment: @LeoDabus, could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Just remove the `do catch` and throw the error from your initializer and from the findClassroom method

Comment: Are you referring to the last `do catch`? Which initializer you are referring to?

Comment: `ClassRoom(configuration: configuration)` is already throwing but you don't show what error it's been thrown

Comment: I am referring to the last catch and the first guard. Looks like your `findClassroom`  method returns optional and throws at the same time which doesn't make to much sense

Comment: But I am catching the error in the following line `throw ServiceError.ClassroomApplicationCreation(error)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can simply just use try and the original error will be thrown. Btw your cases should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: You can switch the error when calling `createClassroom`

Comment: @LeoDabus, would you mind to illustrate as an answer? Your answers are always being quite helpful.

Comment: If you add your initializer and findClassroom methods would be easier to show.

Comment: Btw findClassroom should return an URL

Comment: I have added `findClassroom` method in my question.

Comment: what about ClassRoom initializer?

Comment: That is not my class actually, it comes from third party component as `@interface ClassRoom : NSObject`

Comment: show you retrieveClassroom method. Btw You should save the URL to UserDefaults and return a non optional

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ClassRoom(configuration: configuration)` throws `.classroomApplicationCreation`  and `findClassroom` throws `.classRoomSelectionError` on failure and returns a non optional on success the code can be reduced to

```
enum ServiceError: Error {
   case classroomApplicationCreation(Error)
   case userDoesNotExist(Error) 
   case classRoomSelectionError
}

func createClassroom() throws -> ClassRoom {
    let selectedClass = try findClassroom()
    guard let classURL = URL(string: selectedClass) else {
       throw ServiceError.userDoesNotExist
    }
    let authority = try Authority(url: classURL)
    let configuration = ClassroomApplicationConfig(classId: selectedClass.ID, redirectUri: nil, authority: authority)
    return try ClassRoom(configuration: configuration)
}
```

And the return type is supposed to be `ClassRoom`.

Comment: I have fixed `findClassroom()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor so you don't have any guards or do/catch blocks:

```
func createClassroom() throws -> ClassRoom {
    let selectedClass = try findClassroom()
    let classURL = try makeClassURL(from: selectedClass)
    let authority = try Authority(url: classURL)
    let configuration = ClassroomApplicationConfig(classId: selectedClass.ID, redirectUri: nil, authority: authority)
    return try makeClassRoom(from: configuration)
}


func findClassroom() throws -> String {
    guard allIsWell else { throw ServiceError.ClassRoomSelectionError }
    return ""
}

func makeClassURL(from string: String) throws -> URL {
    guard let classURL = URL(string: string) else {
        throw ServiceError.UserDoesNotExist
    }
    return classURL
}

func makeClassRoom(from configuration: ClassroomApplicationConfig) throws -> ClassRoom {
    do {
        return try ClassRoom(configuration: configuration)
    } catch {
        throw ServiceError.ClassroomApplicationCreation(error)
    }
}
```